# Is there a way to redirect url with embedded query param

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to write a redirect rule that redirects urls of the form:

http://example.com/?lang=fr/hub/anypagehere => http://example.com/hub/anypagehere/?lang=fr

only if there is "hub" in the url.

Is there a way to do this with .htaccess?

Comment: Regular expressions?

Comment: Yes, there is. Take a look at http://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-query-string-redirects/ . I have no time to answer this right now, but I will come back later and answer if no one provides a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)\/hub\/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /hub/%2/?lang=%1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Avoid hardcoding the domain and etc in files, even in the .htaccess.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([a-z]{2})/(hub/.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /%2/?lang=%1 [R=301,L]
```